# how can i get the screen per hours on days of the weeks, in web like analytics android app?

Tags: android, google-analytics

i am a new in google analytics, and i just put it in me mobile application, for me is important to know the use of application by hours in the days of the weeks.

but

i can see this report in analytics android app
http://goo.gl/Ld2d0q

but i can't find it in analytics in web version, i see this
http://goo.gl/D882nX

anybody know how can i get this report in analytics web??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isnt a standard report on the web exaclt like the one in the android picture.    You can try adding hour as a secondary dimension to a standard report.

But i think you would have better results with a custom dashboard widget or a custom report for it.

Dashboard im not happy with it there is a max of 10 rows 24 hours not going to work

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=xCOiy_g1QoaoIr3qvgvFIw

See why i love custom reports this is nice
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=N0p4IQSGSqyWxk9V2QU57Q

Comment: thanks, but the first image is from the official app of Google Analytics for Android Device and if you see the first screenshot of the application in appstore of android, you can see the same report [link](http://goo.gl/WBmRW)

then the android application is the official application.

Comment: Hope the links help they should just add to your account.  There is no data shared.